# flex zend amf - display results in different labels

Tags: apache-flex, zend-framework, datagrid, dataprovider, zend-amf

I've got a simple app that is currently getting information form a database and just displaying the content into a datagrid.

Instead of having this information displayed in a datagrid, I'd like to display it in a couple of labels (first name, last name, phone, etc.), but I'm not really sure how to.

Currently on creationComplete I call my php query function - which looks like this.

```
public function getPeople() {
        return mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_people ORDER BY pers_name ASC");
    }
```

Then I'm just putting my results into a datagrid

```
<mx:DataGrid id="empdg"  x="22" y="184" dataProvider="{amfcall.getPeople.lastResult}" click="showName()">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="ID" dataField="pers_id" editable="false"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="pers_name"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Image" dataField="pers_img"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Job" dataField="pers_job"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Bio" dataField="pers_bio"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Eventually my query will be modified and will only ever return 1 row from the database. So how do I get the results to display in labels instead of the datagrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague at best, but here's me trying anyway:

```
<s:Label text="First Name: {data.firstName}" />
<s:Label text="Last Name: {data.lastName}" />
<s:Label text="Phone: {data.phone}" />
```

I recommend you read up on how on to do binding and look up examples on data driven Flex application, like [this one on my blog](http://www.michelboudreau.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/ParsleyWorkshop-Full.zip).

Comment: Added more details to my question. Hope this makes it a little easier to understand.

Comment: Yeah, I just showed you how to do it.  Copy/paste the line for each one of your dataFields.  Also, it must be noted that what you're doing is extremely insecure.  SQL queries going over the wire is just asking for someone to hack your system and delete your data.  PHP should always be the one doing all the SQL.